# How to get continuous LED flash in Arduino? [C/C++]

Tags: c++, c, flash, loops, arduino

I have a simple Arduino program that uploads the sensor value of a temperature sensor to a Google Spreadsheet every 5 seconds. It all works fine. I have 3 LED's. One that turns on permanently when the setup is complete, one that flashes when the value is being uploaded and one that turns on for 3 seconds when the upload is complete.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to get the pin 3 LED to flash while the value is being uploaded. Wherever I place it it seems to run just once and continue with the rest of the program. I realise this is a really basic logic problem but I can't figure it out and would really appreciate some help!

Here is the main program.

```
/* Setup shield-specific #include statements */
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <Temboo.h>
#include "TembooArduino.h" // Contains Temboo account information


WiFiClient client;

int numRuns = 1;   // Execution count, so this doesn't run forever
int maxRuns = 3;   // Maximum number of times the Choreo should be executed


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(A0,INPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  // For debugging, wait until the serial console is connected.
  delay(4000);
  while(!Serial);

  int wifiStatus = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

  // Determine if the WiFi Shield is present.
  Serial.print("\n\nShield:");
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("FAIL");

    // If there's no WiFi shield, stop here.
    while(true);
  }

  Serial.println("OK");

  // Try to connect to the local WiFi network.
  while(wifiStatus != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("WiFi:");
    wifiStatus = WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WPA_PASSWORD);

    if (wifiStatus == WL_CONNECTED) {
      Serial.println("OK");
    } else {
      Serial.println("FAIL");
    }
    delay(5000);
  }

  Serial.println("Setup complete.\n");
  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
}

void loop() {
    if (numRuns <= maxRuns)
      { 
    Serial.println("Running AppendRow - Run #" + String(numRuns++) + "\n");

    int sensorVal = analogRead(A0);

    //two lines to test the sensor value in serial output 
    Serial.print("sensor Value: "); 
    Serial.print(sensorVal);

    float voltage = (sensorVal/1024.0) * 5.0; //testing voltage output in serial 

    Serial.print(", volts "); 
    Serial.print(voltage); 

    float temperature = (voltage - .5) * 100; 

    Serial.print(", temperature in C ");
    Serial.print(temperature);
    Serial.print("\n");

    TembooChoreo AppendRowChoreo(client);


    // Invoke the Temboo client
    AppendRowChoreo.begin();

    // Set Temboo account credentials
    AppendRowChoreo.setAccountName(TEMBOO_ACCOUNT);
    AppendRowChoreo.setAppKeyName(TEMBOO_APP_KEY_NAME);
    AppendRowChoreo.setAppKey(TEMBOO_APP_KEY);

    // Set Choreo inputs
    String UsernameValue = "xxxx";
    AppendRowChoreo.addInput("Username", UsernameValue);
    String PasswordValue = "xxxx";
    AppendRowChoreo.addInput("Password", PasswordValue);
    String RowDataValue = (String)analogRead(A0);
    AppendRowChoreo.addInput("RowData", RowDataValue);
    String SpreadsheetTitleValue = "TempSensor";
    AppendRowChoreo.addInput("SpreadsheetTitle", SpreadsheetTitleValue);

    // Identify the Choreo to run
    AppendRowChoreo.setChoreo("/Library/Google/Spreadsheets/AppendRow");
    // Run the Choreo; when results are available, print them to serial
    AppendRowChoreo.run();
    while(AppendRowChoreo.available()) 
    {
      char c = AppendRowChoreo.read();
      Serial.print(c);
    }
    AppendRowChoreo.close();

    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    delay(3000);      
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);

      }

  Serial.println("\nWaiting...\n");
  delay(5000); // wait 5 seconds between AppendRow calls
}
```

Here is the loop I would like to implement

```
void flash()
{
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    delay(100);
}
```

starting at

```
TembooChoreo AppendRowChoreo(client);
```

and ending at

```
AppendRowChoreo.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Timer Library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer). This library allows you to run tasks after certain delays without using the delay() function.

The library is an implementation that uses timer interrupts to schedule tasks. You could do the same thing by hand.

The main idea to see here is that using delay() to schedule tasks is generally wasteful, as it locks the processor into doing nothing - "busy waiting". Instead, embedded programmers need to learn about using timer interrupts that interrupt the main "thread" to run tasks without wasting processor cycles.